# how to convert from one date format to another in mysql

Tags: mysql, date-comparison

I am using MySQL and I want to get all the dates in the previous week from a column, say `xyz`, which is of type date and has the format `YYYY-MM-DD`. However, when I use

```
select 
    * 
from 
    tablename 
where 
    xyz > date_sub(curdate(),INTERVAL 1 week);
```

I get dates which are not within the past 1 week. I get dates which are one month from now and some random dates.

Comment: It's hard to answer such a question well without an example of your data and the table schema.

Answer (score 0):

You query is pulling all records in which `xyz` (your date column I assume) is newer than one week ago. This could in fact be future records. If you want to exclusively view things from the previous week, you need to use the `between` keyword.

```
select
    *
from
    tablename
where
    xyz between date_sub(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 week) and curdate()
```